# General Function Failure: failed to connect to database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase, connection

I am trying to access the file geodatabase and I get a message of General Function Failure: failed to connect to database. I can access other file geodatasabses, the problem is only with this one. I was doing Network Analysis in this file  geodatabase, in case it's relevant.

I could not find any relevant solutions. Do you have any idea what could be the reason?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.
[image]

Comment: You can try tool Recover File Geodatabase: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/recover-file-geodatabase.htm

Comment: Your file geodatabase has been corrupted. You'll need to fall back to an archived/backup snapshot.

Comment: Thanks  a lot! I've just recovered it and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try tool [Recover File Geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/recover-file-geodatabase.htm):

> Recovers data from a file geodatabase that has become corrupt.